# Using Trap in Unix Scripts

Tags: unix

I have written a script to transfer files from one server to another.

Firstly i am creating a tar of all the zipped files on one server and then i am transferring tar to another server.

Upon successful transfer i am doing Untar of files on both the sever.

I need to know one thing that how can i use Unix TRAP functionality in handling Restartability and Errors if anyhow tar file got corrupt of transfer got failed.

If any error exists i need to bring the execution back to its initial state.

Below mentioned is the small piece of code from my script

```
tar -cvf files_to_send.tar *.txt -C ${1} 
          RC=$?
          if [ ${RC} -ne 0 ]; then
             echo "Unable to Create Tar files of received files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
             rm -f *_end >> ${LOG_FILE}
             return 1
          fi

          cd ${1}
          gzip files_to_send.tar
          RC=$?
          if [ ${RC} -ne 0 ]; then
             echo "Unable to Create Zip of tar files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
             echo "Deleting End Files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
             rm -f *_end >> ${LOG_FILE}
             echo "Deleting tar file" >> ${LOG_FILE}
             rm -f ${1}/files_to_send.tar >> ${LOG_FILE}
             return 1
          fi


          cd ${1}
          chmod 775 files_to_send.tar.gz  >> ${LOG_FILE}
          RC=$?

          if [ ${RC} -ne 0 ]; then
             echo "Unable to change permissions of tar and end files" > ${LOG_FILE}
             echo "Deleting End Files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
             rm -f *_end >> ${LOG_FILE}
             echo "Deleting Zipped tar file" >> ${LOG_FILE}
             rm -f ${SOURCE_DIR}/files_to_send.tar.gz >> ${LOG_FILE}
             return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
trap 'do_something' ERR # start special error handling
tar ... # if the command fails, do_something will be executed
trap - ERR # stopping special error handling
```

`do_something` can be a function, a command or a script.

But you don't even need `trap` if you handle error cases properly. I wrote a version of your script with *boolean logic*, no need to store the return code in a variable, see :

```
if tar -cvf files_to_send.tar *.txt -C ${1}; then
    echo "Unable to Create Tar files of received files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    rm -f *_end >> ${LOG_FILE}
    return 1
fi

cd ${1}

if gzip files_to_send.tar; then
    echo "Unable to Create Zip of tar files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    echo "Deleting End Files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    rm -f *_end >> ${LOG_FILE}
    echo "Deleting tar file" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    rm -f ${1}/files_to_send.tar >> ${LOG_FILE}
    return 1
fi


cd ${1}
if chmod 775 files_to_send.tar.gz >> ${LOG_FILE}; then
    echo "Unable to change permissions of tar and end files" > ${LOG_FILE}
    echo "Deleting End Files" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    rm -f *_end >> ${LOG_FILE}
    echo "Deleting Zipped tar file" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    rm -f ${SOURCE_DIR}/files_to_send.tar.gz >> ${LOG_FILE}
    return 1
fi
```

Comment: if i am using Return Codes in my script do i still need to add trap?

Comment: No, you can use both or _boolean logic_ like : `if tar...; then echo ok; else echo NOK; fi`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this is how i am doing it using booleans as mentioned below.    mv ${SOURCE_DIR}/files_to_send.tar.gz ${MOVE_DIR} >> ${LOG_FILE}

          RC=$?

          if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Unable to Move files to temp directory" >> ${LOG_FILE}
            rm -f ${SOURCE_DIR}/files_to_send.tar.gz; rm -f ${SOURCE_DIR}/*_end >> ${LOG_FILE}
            exit 1

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution. My other question is that is there any issue if i save value of return code of command in a variable.. because the thing is that i have completed the script and i need to deliver it asap so i don't wanna make any big changes to it at this point.  Please let me know will i be missing any error/restartibility scenario if i will be using Return Codes to handle it?

Comment: There's no problem to keep return code as you do, it's just not that elegant, nor concise